# preg_match(); - Unknown modifier '+'

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

Alright, so I'm currently working on parsing an RSS feed. I've gotten the data I need no problem, and all I have left is parsing the game title.

Here is the code I currently have (ignore the sloppiness, it is just a proof of concept):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://raptr.com/conexion/rss';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$lastgame = $xml->channel->item[0]->description;
preg_match('[a-zA-Z]+</a>.$', $lastgame, $match);

echo $match;
?>
```

Everything was working great, but then I started getting this error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: 
Unknown modifier '+' in raptr.php on line 14
```

The only thing I have left is to strip out the closing anchor tag and the period, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't liking the '+'. Any ideas?

Edit: This should not be marked as a duplicate as it was asked two years before the other question.

Comment: Inspecting the rss feed, you don't want to use the `$` there.

Comment: When I remove the $ it only matches "Conexion", I appreciate the help though!

Comment: What did you intend to match? All links by any chance? Then try `preg_match_all`. Otherwise try an RSS parser.

Comment: I just want the most recent game played. It is always the text within the second link. I wish they organized the feed better.

Comment: Use preg_match_all and get the second entry.

Comment: @mario - It sort of works, but for some reason it is returning an array inside of an array - `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Conexion [1] => Minecraft ) ) `

Comment: Yes, that's the difference to the normal preg_match which would just return one result.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to use delimiters with regexes in PHP. You can use the often used `/`, but PHP lets you use any matching characters, so `@` and `#` are popular.

[Further Reading](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

If you are interpolating variables inside your regex, be sure to pass the delimiter you chose as the second argument to [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Comment: Well, that was a surprise. `string preg_quote ( string $str [, string $delimiter = NULL ] )` -> function signature forces nothing as default, thus kicked me in the balls when least expected. Default should be `/`.

Answer (score 30):

Try this code:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+<\/a>.$/', $lastgame, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Using `/` as a delimiter means you also need to escape it here, like so: <\/a>.

**UPDATE**

```
preg_match('/<a.*<a.*>(.*)</', $lastgame, $match);
echo'['.$match[1].']';
```

Might not be the best way...

Comment: print_r($match); returns "Array ( )"I'm pretty sure my expression is correct.

Comment: I don't know what you tried to say with your comment...

Comment: @Conexion, checked your other comments, what is it you are trying to pull from that rss feed into your match ? The games ?

Comment: Yup, just trying to pull the most recent game :)

Comment: It works, but the problem is, the feed doesn't always being with "played some". Sorry I'm being difficult!

Comment: Updated my code yet again, considered this time you always have <a>USER</a> <a>Game</a> in that order.

Answer (score 6):

This happened to me because I put a variable in the regex and sometimes its string value included a slash. Solution: [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about preg_quote - very useful function!

Answer (score 1):

May be this will be usefull for u:
[ReGExp on-line editor](https://regexr.com//)