# Php Password validation should not contain username and full name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on password validations. All other validations are working fine. I have to add initials validation on password. Password should not contain full name or username and first/last character of username and full name. I am trying to get it with strpos function but it's not working.This is my code i had tried with 2 ways but not working.

```
<?php

$name = "katlina john smith";
$uname = "testinguser";
$password = "john";
$password = "kjs@123"; // first initials of name
$password = "testing@ps"; //These password format should not be accepted

if (strpos($password,$name) !== false || strpos($password,$uname) !== false) {
    echo 'Username found in the password';
}

//2nd way

if (preg_match("#(($uname)|($name))#", $password))
{
    
     echo 'Username found in the password';
}
```

Comment: try it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761201/password-different-than-username-name-email

Comment: Swap both value strpos first argument will be your string and the second will the substring you're trying to search.Error is here your if condition should be 
if (strpos($name,$password) !== false || strpos($uname, $password) !== false) {

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer

```
$name = "katlina john smith";
$uname = "testinguser";
$password = "john";
if ( (strpos($name,$password) !== false ) || ( strpos($uname,$password ) !== 
false ) ) {
 echo 'password not valid';
 }
```

Comment: now it's not working with password="katlina@test123"

Comment: is there not any other way. I have to check all character of name and uname. user should not user any value of name and username in password

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$name = "katlina john smith";
$username = "testinguser";
$password = "katlina@test123";
```

For PHP 7:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($password), strtolower($username)) === false || passContainsName($name, $password)) {
    echo 'password not valid in PHP 7'.PHP_EOL;
 }
 
 
 function passContainsName($name, $password){
     foreach (explode(" ", $name) as $toCheck) {
         if (strpos(strtolower($password), strtolower($toCheck)) === false) {
            return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

For PHP 8:

```
if (str_contains(strtolower($password), strtolower($username)) || passContainsName($name,$password)) {
 echo 'password not valid';
 }
 
 
 function passContainsName($name, $password){
     foreach (explode(" ", $name) as $toCheck) {
         if (str_contains(strtolower($password), strtolower($toCheck))) {
            return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

fiddle [here] with php 7 and 8 examples[1](https://paiza.io/projects/lKTN-97WO0ctq2u3x1bCgw)

Comment: str_contains() works in php 8 and my php version is 7.

Comment: added php 7 version to example and fiddle.