# PHP- Preg_replace tag name and its contents

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string like 
`string(8234) "<style>.{ margin-bottom:10px; float:left; display: inline-block; width:56%; text-align:left; padding-right:20px; padding-left:20px; } . > p { display: table-cell; height: 150px; vertical-align: middle; }..................</style>.................`
I want to remove `<style>` tag and all its contents.
I have tried

```
$description = $product_info['description']; // the string with style tag
$text = preg_replace('/<\s*style.+?<\s*\/\s*style.*?>/si', ' ', $description );
echo $text;
```

but it shows the same string without removing `<style>` tag.
I have also tried to replace only `<style>` tag by doing

```
$text    = str_replace("<style>", "", $description);
```

but this also doesn't work at all. I am seeing the same string again and again. I have also tried it with `DOMParser`

```
 $doc =   new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTML($description);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 foreach ($xpath->query('//style') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
 }
 $text    =    $doc->saveHTML();
```

but in all cases, output is the same with `<style>` and its contents

Comment: make var_dump($description) before preg_replace, because your code seems to be fine;

Comment: both `var_dump()` are same,

Comment: if  you take your string from the page displaying by php, you may not see that your string is `&lt;script&gt;` because probably it is saved in DB in such form

Comment: Yes exactly, How to do that? When I do `var_dump()` on the same string, I see `string(8234)` but when I pasted the string on IDEone and did `var_dump()` I saw `string(6413)`

Comment: `html_entity_decode() `

Comment: It actually worked with `html_entity_decode()` and then `preg_replace()` as explained in sweaver2112's answer

Comment: It works with your Reyes too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex [does work](http://ideone.com/v9Jyuz), but might I suggest a [simpler pattern](http://ideone.com/HO4RMY), using non-greedy quantifers:

```
<style>.*?<\/style>
```

Comment: I am seeing this error, could you please write the complete line?`Unknown modifier .`

Comment: check the IDEone links. One is yours, one is the simpler pattern.

Comment: unknown modifier might indicate unescaped pattern delimiters (`/`) should be (`\/`) ? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5589826/244811

Comment: well it works on IDEone, but it is not working for my `string` should I paste the complete string here?

Comment: modify the IDEone with your input string, and give the link.

Comment: http://ideone.com/q9JjxV is the link. I don't know what's wrong here, it is working on IDEone but not on my system. I am getting the string directly from `db`, Do I have to do something to make the string in raw form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112532/discussion-between-baig772-and-sweaver2112).