# php collect all the values that match a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I tried to load a html file with values to replace, but first i want to get all of them... but preg_match_all always return NULL.

The result of "`var_dump($htmlcontent);`" :

```
string(643) "<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="solved" value="1" onchange="...">
    </td>
    <td>{{description}}</td>
    <td>{{solved}}</td>
    <td>
```

[...]

And:

```
$bla = preg_match_all( '\{\{(\w+)\}\}', 'bla {{ble}}', $dataToFill);

var_dump($bla); // bool(false) 
var_dump($dataToFill); //NULL
```

and I don't know by. The regular expression works in all the online testers I tried, so, what's happends?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589807/preg-match-unknown-modifier. You just need regex delimiters.

Comment: one hour looking for an answer and it was answered. But maybe with two similar questions the next find the answer faster. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add delimiters to your regex.

```
$bla = preg_match_all('/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/', 'bla {{ble}}', $dataToFill);
```