# regex match 2 characters / and -

Tags: regex

I have a regex that looks like this:

```
/(((\+|00)32[ ]?(?:\(0\)[ ]?)?)|0){1}(4(60|[789]\d)\/?(\s?\d{2}\.?){2}(\s?\d{2})|(\d\/?\s?\d{3}|\d{2}\/?\s?\d{2})(\.?\s?\d{2}){2})/g
```

this matches: `+32 16/894477` but `+32 16-894477` doesn't

this `20150211-0001731015-1` also matches but this shouldn't match

I am trying to fix my regex here:

https://regex101.com/r/LmaIPA/1

Comment: The hyphen is not matched, and you can add a whitspace boundary to the right https://regex101.com/r/8ZSpfD/1 at first glance. Do you need all those separate capture groups?

Comment: Or a `(?!-?\d)` lookahead, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ZSpfD/2).

Comment: @Thefourthbird when i use your regex in my PHP 7.4 code i get an `Unknown modifier '-' in` any idea why?

Comment: @MikloVuba See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705399/warning-preg-replace-unknown-modifier and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589807/preg-match-unknown-modifier Did you use delimiters?

Comment: @Thefourthbird no i did not I copy pasted it from regex site

Comment: You can see generated demo code here https://regex101.com/r/2SoMHJ/1/codegen?language=php

Comment: @Thefourthbird okay I used delimiters it works great

Answer (score 0):

```
 (((\+|00)32[ ]?(?:\(0\)[ ]?)?)|0){1}(4(60|[789]\d)\/?(\s?\d{2}\.?){2}(\s?\d{2})|(\d\/?\s?\d{3}|\d{2}(\/?|\-)\s?\d{2})(\.?\s?\d{2}){2})
```

I guess I fixed part of it by adding this but let me know if there something else that doesn't work properly :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of capture groups, and some can also be omitted if you don't need them for after processing.

The issue is that for `+32 16-894477` you are not matching the hyphen, and you match the larger string as there are no boundaries set so you get a partial match.

Some notes:

- You don't have to escape the `/` when using a different delimiter
- You can omit `{1}` from the pattern
- `\s` can also match a newline, you can use `\h` if you want to match a horizontal whitespace char
- A single space `[ ]` does not have to be in a character class

---

You can extend the pattern with adding the hyphen and forward slash to a character class using `[/-]?`, wrap the whole pattern in a non capture group  and assert a whitspace boundary to the right  `(?:whole pattern here)(?!\S)`

A version without the capture groups for a match only:

```
(?:(?:(?:\+|00)32\h?(?:\(0\)\h?)?|0)(?:4(?:60|[789]\d)/?(?:\h?\d{2}\.?){2}\h?\d{2}|(?:\d/?\h?\d{3}|\d{2}[/-]?\h?\d{2})(?:\.?\h?\d{2}){2}))(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pzgq9u/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/0gLhn)

Php example

```
$re = '~(?:(?:(?:\+|00)32\h?(?:\(0\)\h?)?|0)(?:4(?:60|[789]\d)/?(?:\h?\d{2}\.?){2}\h?\d{2}|(?:\d/?\h?\d{3}|\d{2}[/-]?\h?\d{2})(?:\.?\h?\d{2}){2}))(?!\S)~';
$str = 'OK 01/07 - 31/07  
OK 0487207339
OK +32487207339
OK 01.07.2016
OK +32 (0)16 89 44 77
OK 016894477
OK 003216894477
OK +3216894477
OK 016/89.44.77
OK +32 16894477
OK 0032 16894477
OK +32 16/894477
NOK +32 16-894477 (this should match)
OK 0479/878810
NOK 20150211-0001731015-1 (this shouldn\'t match)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0487207339
    [1] => +32487207339
    [2] => +32 (0)16 89 44 77
    [3] => 016894477
    [4] => 003216894477
    [5] => +3216894477
    [6] => 016/89.44.77
    [7] => +32 16894477
    [8] => 0032 16894477
    [9] => +32 16/894477
    [10] => +32 16-894477
    [11] => 0479/878810
)
```